# is there any exception with error code in stl?

Tags: c++, exception, boost, stl

I read several discussion on the use of exception and error code and when each of them is suitable.

I believe in my case exceptions are better, but I have one specific problem:

if I throw a std::runtime_error("this is an error") and then I catch it, I can not find what was the error, I just understand that there was an error.

What I am looking is an exception that I can throw and add an error code to it so later I can check the error code when I catch it, some thing such as this:

```
 enum errorCodes
 {
        error_1,
        error_2,
        error_3
 }

 try
 {
     throw std::runtime_error(error_1,"can not do the job!");
 }
 catch (std::runtime_error & err)
 {
     switch (err.errorCode)
     {
         case error_1:
            // I can not contunue, so re throw it
             rethrow err;
         case error_2:
            // it is not important for me, so I can continue
           break;
        case error_3: 
            //Oh, I need to do something before continue
            re_init();
            break;
        default:
             rethrow err;
  }
```

I can write such exception, but before doing this, I am wondering if such type of exception exist in STL or BOOST?

Is there any better way of doing this ( I am not interested to throw different type of exception, so catching different type of exception is not a solution from my point of view.

Comment: *"( I am not interested to throw different type of exception, so catching different type of exception is not a solution from my point of view."* But IMO, it is the way to go. You can get rid of your switch and only catch error you want to manage (in your example only `error_2` and `error_3`)

Comment: @Jarod42 but that means you need to develop different type of exceptions and throw them . as an example if I want to read a file, I may have two error: file name is not valid and there is no memory so even for a simple task of reading the content of a file into a buffer, I need two type of exceptions, which is not good.

Comment: I prefer specific exception ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b5d8f52b7bd966e)) over error code ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45ee82736f244a1b))

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error). It's derived from `std::runtime_error`. It's pretty Unix-land-oriented but it does support error codes in general, and I suggest that you use it that way.

---

The following code demonstrates how to define one's own error category for application specific error codes:

```
#include <string>
#include <system_error>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace my{
    struct Error_code
    {
        enum Enum
        {
            error_1 = 101,
            error_2 = 102,
            error_3 = 103
        };
    };

    class App_error_category
        : public std::error_category
    {
    using Base = std::error_category;
    public:
        auto name() const noexcept
            -> char const*
            override
        { return "App error"; }

        auto default_error_condition( int const code ) const noexcept
            -> std::error_condition
            override
        { (void) code; return {}; }

        auto equivalent( int const code, std::error_condition const& condition ) const noexcept
            -> bool
            override
        { (void) code; (void) condition; return false; }

        // The intended functionality of this func is pretty unclear.
        // It apparently can't do its job (properly) in the general case.
        auto equivalent( std::error_code const& code, int const condition ) const noexcept
            -> bool
            override
        { return Base::equivalent( code, condition ); }

        auto message( int const condition ) const
            -> std::string
            override
        { return "An application error occurred, code = " + std::to_string( condition ); }

        constexpr
        App_error_category(): Base{} {}
    };

    auto app_error_category()
        -> App_error_category const&
    {
        static App_error_category the_instance;
        return the_instance;
    }

    class App_error
        : public std::system_error
    {
    using Base = std::system_error;
    public:
        auto app_error_code() const
            -> Error_code::Enum
        { return static_cast<Error_code::Enum>( code().value() ); }

        App_error( Error_code::Enum const code )
            : Base{ code, app_error_category() }
        {}

        App_error( Error_code::Enum const code, std::string const& description )
            : Base{ code, app_error_category(), description }
        {}
    };

}  // namespace my

void foo()
{
    try
    {
        throw my::App_error( my::Error_code::error_1, "can not do the job!" );
    }
    catch( my::App_error const& x )
    {
        switch( x.app_error_code() )
        {
        case my::Error_code::error_1:
            // I can not contunue, so re throw it
            throw;
        case my::Error_code::error_2:
            // it is not important for me, so I can continue
            break;
        case my::Error_code::error_3: 
            //Oh, I need to do something before continue
            //re_init();
            break;
        }
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
using namespace std;
auto main()
    -> int
{
    try
    {
        foo();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        cerr << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

With both Visual C++ 2015 and MingW g++ 6.4.0 this produces the output

```
!can not do the job!: An application error occurred, code = 101
```

---

In general it's more practical to define specific exception classes than to use error codes. However, for system error codes it's more practical to just pass these codes up with the exception. And for *that* the complexity shown above can be avoided, since the `std::system_category` is then eminently suitable.

In short, the complexity here stems from your requirement to not go with the flow, but in a direction somewhat against the current.

Comment: so how I can create custom error codes and make sure that they are not colliding with system generated error codes?

Comment: @mans: You use a "category."  I whipped up some code which ALMOST works, maybe you can figure out how to fix it: https://godbolt.org/g/WMhvDU

Comment: @mans: Check out the [constructor documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/system_error). Essentially there's a typed code and an [error category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_category). The error category defines the meaning of the error code value.

Comment: thanks: What is this means? is it part of C++ 14? I can not see it in C++ 11

Comment: This is all stuff introduced in C++11. I've linked to the relevant online docs. In the PDFs of the standard you can just use the search function.

Comment: sorry, my comment was not complete: what is this: auto main()
    -> int

Comment: That's the `main` function. Every standard C++ program needs one. Possibly you're unfamiliar with modern (post C++11) function declaration syntax; if so read up on trailing return type.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) out of the box.

Note that using simply `throw;` without an argument is a *far* better way of re-throwing your exception (you seem to be using `throw err;`) since the former will throw the exception *by reference* rather than *by value*: the latter can cause object slicing.

Comment: Since "rethrow err" is syntactically invalid as C++ code, I submit that it's intended as pseudo-code.

Comment: I did bury a "seem" in there to cover my a** ;-) How about I upvote your answer if you let me nick your reference to `std::system_error`? (which I've just done).